# Does C++ rand() function include the endpoints?

Tags: c++

My question is does the `rand()` function include the end points or not include them in possible values to be returned.

```
rand() % 10 + 1
```

Does that return values in the range 2-9 or 1-10?

Comment: Dude. Read the documentation.

Comment: Or just run it twenty times and see what the heck happens?

Comment: `rand()` is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good call.

Comment: `rand() % 10` will be a value between 0-9.  Thus, `rand() % 10 + 1` will be from 1-10.

Comment: From the man-page: "The rand() function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to RAND_MAX inclusive". But as @Benjamin Lindley mentioned, the modulo is relevant.

Comment: so much love :). Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) of `rand()`:

> Returns a pseudo-random integral value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX **(0 and RAND_MAX included)**.

Emphasis mine.

However, as [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley) correctly points out in the comments, `rand()` is irrelevant to the result in this question. The key to the question is the modulus operator `%`.

Because the modulus operator results in the remainder of the division of the left operand by the right operand, the value of anything `rand()` could produce, `% 10`, will be between `0` and `9`. Because `1` is added to the result of that operation, the final output will be between `1` and `10`.

I would like to add that [djechlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339987/djechlin) is correct both in his comment to this answer and in his answer, that the answer to questions like "*what does this function do?*" is generally best and quickest found by searching for the name of the language and the name of the function with a search engine such a [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/) or [Bing](http://www.bing.com/) or alternatively the documentation for the language, such as [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) for c++.

Comment: Gosh, -1 for doing *all* the work. Would have for this user to think this is how finding programming answers works.

Comment: No, I'm not actually joking this time. There's several meta discussions about this. There's definitely a line where it does more damage to all parties to answer extremely poor questions.

Comment: @djechlin Which is why I actually explain _why_ the answer is what it is. Hopefully they learn something.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a disservice to the community to answer your question directly. Therefore I'm leaving you with a method that if you choose to understand and run yourself, should give you the answer:

```
int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::cout << rand() % 10 + 1 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More generally questions about how functions work are usually answered in the documentation for the said function. Without much trouble you should be able to find it yourself by googling something like "c++ rand". Again it would be a disservice to spoonfeed too much, but if you have a real problem with the documentation you can amend your question here.

Comment: the q is so bad i want to downvote your answer. (but i didnt)

Comment: come on, at 19K does it matter?

Comment: @djechlin: It also doesn't compile.

Comment: @DarkDust too much javascript. fixed.

Comment: It's a shame no close reason applies to this question anymore.

Comment: @MK Okay, I'll accept my +1/-1 and be on with my day. Adios.

Comment: @djechlin just to get the record straight -- i didn't end up voting one way or the other :)